# AJAX call cancelled without being sent, no error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I hit the following API to get data with PHP

```
$data= file_get_contents("$servIp/local/getMyDataJson.php?variable=$variable");
```

I'm trying to do the same thing with AJAX but the request gets canceled and I am not getting an error message

```
$.ajax({
         url: "/local/getMyDataJson.php",
         type: 'GET',
         data:'variable='+variable,
         success: function (msg) {
             console.log("Hit getMyData");
             console.log(msg);
         },
         error: function () {
             console.log("error in hitting getMyData");
             console.log("error="+error);
         }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And whats in your console?

Comment: anyway, error function parameters is: `Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )` So `error: function (jqXHR, error, errorThrown ) {`

Comment: Can you provide more details?
If you are triggering this on a link, make sure its default behavior has been prevented with `preventDefault()` or `return false`

Comment: @Paulie. If you select "inspect element" from your browser and then go to "Network" option, you will see this request referenced.
Sometimes, Ajax Requests doesn't show errors in console which we have second way out to find this error.
Select your script request and then find another option inside a small window opened on right-side called "Response".
Inside "Response" you will find possible error that possible could be some syntax errors.If you find anything, please update your question with this information so we can help you.